# mosquitto mqtt broker tls problem. IP doesn not match certificate's altnames

Tags: node.js, ssl, openssl, mqtt, mosquitto

I have provided the broker and the client with certificates. The broker is avaible at 172.27.224.1.

When I try to connect with the client, I get following error message:

```
Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: IP: 172.27.224.1 is not in the cert's list:
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at Object.checkServerIdentity (node:tls:297:12)
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1540:27)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:944:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:725:12) {
  reason: "IP: 172.27.224.1 is not in the cert's list: ",
  host: '172.27.224.1',
  cert: {
    subject: [Object: null prototype] {
      C: 'AU',
      ST: 'Some-State',
      O: '',
      OU: '',
      CN: '172.27.224.1'
    },
    issuer: [Object: null prototype] {
      C: 'DE',
      ST: 'Some-State',
      O: '',
      OU: '',
      CN: '172.27.224.1'
    },
    [...]
```

What's the error here? The ca.crt is a self signed cert with issued for 172.27.224.1 and issued from 172.27.224.1. The client.crt is issed from 172.27.224.1 and issued for "username".

should't this work?

Steps I used to generate the certificate:

`openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 2048`
`openssl req -new -x509 -days 1826 -key ca.key -out ca.crt`
`openssl genrsa -out client.key 2048`
`openssl req -new -out client.csr -key client.key`
`openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt -days 360`

I use for the client node.js v16.13 and the [mqtt library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt).

Comment: Use of the CN as the hostname is deprecated. All valid hostname's (and IP addresses) should be listed in SAN fields these days. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73525517/edit) the question to give details of which client you are using and more details how you created the certificate

Comment: Since when is it deprecated to put the hostname in the CN field? I never heared of SAN before. Will older software understand those certs if the hostname is only stated within the SAN field?

Comment: It has been deprecated since 2000 e.g. https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/details-on-https-common-name-deprecation-in-openshift-4.10. As I asked PLEASE edit the question to include details of which library/language you are using so we know where is now enforcing these changes.

Comment: Ok that's crazy. I saw a bunch of tutorials on how to generate certificates but they all did put the hostname in the CN field. Or is this just a thing when generating ca certificates?

Comment: It's for any cert that is used to identify a host as part of a TLS connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using OpenSSL to create the CA cert then you can do it as follows:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -days 3650 -sha256 \
  -keyout ca.key -out ca.crt -reqexts SAN -extensions SAN \
  -subj '/CN=Broker Cert' \
  -config <(cat /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf; printf "[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=IP:172.27.224.1")
```

This makes an assumption that you are using a `openss.cnf` file stored at `/etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf`

But as a rule it's better to create a CA cert and then sign server certs with that as it makes changing things easier and you don't need to update all the clients when you want to change something. It also makes issuing client certificates a lot easier.

Please do still update the question with details of the programming language and client library you are using that is now enforcing the SAN rules.

Comment: So my ca.cert is wrong. I don't use the openss.cnf file. I just use the `openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 2048` and `openssl req -new -x509 -days 1826 -key ca.key -out ca.crt` command for generating. Those commands doesn't prompt me for a subject alt name or similar. How would the command look like without using the openss.cnf file?

Comment: The `openssl.cnf` file is the default version shipped with openssl, where it is located may be different depending what distro you are using (it will be in `/etc/pki`, `/etc/tls` or `/etc/ssl` usually. Just update the path to what ever matches your machine.