# TLS ServerName as IP is not permitted

Tags: node.js, ssl, mqtt

I want to connect to my mqtt broker but when running my client code, I get this error message:

`(node:18196) [DEP0123] DeprecationWarning: Setting the TLS ServerName to an IP address is not permitted by RFC 6066. This will be ignored in a future version.`

How can I fix this? I don't have a domanin name or some other way to reach the broker, just an IP.

All informations on the certificates can be seen on [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73525517/mosquitto-mqtt-broker-tls-problem-ip-doesn-not-match-certificates-altnames).

Client code:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var fs = require('fs');
var certFile = fs.readFileSync("./client.crt");
var keyFile = fs.readFileSync("./client.key");
var caFile = fs.readFileSync("./ca.crt");

console.log("connecting...")
var client = mqtt.connect("mqtts://172.27.224.1:8883",{host: 'mqtts://172.27.224.1', port: '8883', cert: certFile, key: keyFile, ca: caFile, connectTimeout: 5000, username: "user", password: "xxx"})

client.on('connect', function () {
        console.log("Connected")
      client.subscribe('test', function (err) {
        if (!err) {
          console.log("subscribed")
        } else {
                console.log(err);
        }   
      })
    })

    client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
      // message is Buffer
      console.log(message.toString())
    })

    client.on('error', function (err) {
      console.log(err)
      client.end();
      setTimeout(() => {
          client.reconnect()
      }, 20000);
    })

    client.on('reconnect', function () {
      console.log("reconnecting")
    })

    client.on('disconnect', function () {
      console.log("disconnected")
    })

    client.on('offline', function (err) {
      console.log("offline")
    })

    client.on('end', function (err) {
      console.log("end")
    })
```

Comment: Remove the `host` and `port` entries from the options object passed to the `connect` method. It is redundant (and the `host` value is wrong anyway as it should not have a schema)

Comment: Ok I did that. Error is still there.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that would fix it, it was more to make things cleaner. That warning is most likely going to come from the version of OpenSSL your nodejs was built against. You should be able to ignore it for now

Comment: What you list is a deprecation warning, not an error. As such this shoulbn't be the cause of any problem you experience. But yes you should avoid using IP addresses. You can register any public domain and use it as suffix for all your internal naming needs.

Comment: good grief - why should I have to register a domain? Going between to VM's on the same machine... yes yes, only a deprecation - FOR NOW :(