# MQTT TLS with VPS: Mosquitto TLS error (SAN settings?)

Tags: ssl, mqtt, esp32, mosquitto

I tried to follow the approach [from this suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73525517/mosquitto-mqtt-broker-tls-problem-ip-doesn-not-match-certificates-altnames), but still I can't get the settings right. Output of `mosquitto_sub`  (depending on different CA settings):

```
mosquitto_sub --host abc.xyz.com --port 12345 --cafile /.../ca.crt --topic testtopic --username testuser --pw abcdef --debug
Client mosq-2d2wYFdFpeB8tc8Vmr sending CONNECT
OpenSSL Error[0]: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Error: A TLS error occurred.

Client mosq-0dfENGm0nj8iunicEY sending CONNECT
OpenSSL Error[0]: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
Error: A TLS error occurred.
```

Output of `$ user% openssl x509 -in mosquitto.crt -text -noout`:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            54:01:4f:99:1d:88:ff:7e:13:ed:52:24:38:0e:79:b6:7a:17:47:d2
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN=abc.xyz.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Sep 15 23:09:47 2022 GMT
            Not After : Sep 15 23:09:47 2023 GMT
        Subject: CN=abc.xyz.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:a3:94:c0:cc:a4:ab:0a:5c:a0:bf:e1:c3:05:4d:
                    19:34:0d:e7:66:d9:c5:d2:f3:a1:85:58:1d:dd:83:
                    30:20:11:35:59:33:00:90:de:51:f6:e7:48:79:19:
                    f6:03:1f:e8:ec:70:95:ce:0b:30:24:1e:59:8a:8e:
                    9e:a7:95:3f:f8:2d:4a:5a:53:9d:70:19:3a:2a:b4:
                    25:d7:90:8d:65:5a:db:4a:ce:3f:d5:68:e7:8d:b2:
                    a7:10:e3:70:e8:ae:dd:0a:5a:a4:f3:7a:d7:37:94:
                    7d:97:04:3f:d0:5c:55:97:b4:78:e3:0a:37:41:c3:
                    f3:04:0c:ec:b5:62:ed:0e:f0:3b:53:fe:5a:1c:1d:
                    be:6f:a7:04:b3:7b:e5:9c:e1:24:af:13:41:d6:9c:
                    25:57:81:0d:a0:9a:3a:03:e7:2a:ef:32:be:dc:c9:
                    8d:d6:ff:10:27:fd:fb:43:03:90:21:17:ed:33:50:
                    5f:6c:3b:fe:20:62:b4:a2:16:d4:68:5d:67:2d:6b:
                    04:e5:a7:2b:4c:5b:ea:65:a8:42:f1:0c:67:f0:90:
                    d9:06:da:b4:5e:73:27:f5:37:54:5b:dc:a8:cf:73:
                    3e:df:12:c5:e0:f9:90:a1:62:ec:6b:7a:7b:54:15:
                    bd:9e:5d:1d:dc:69:d0:8d:62:86:69:74:fb:a7:3c:
                    a6:f3
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:abc.xyz.com
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                D6:91:BE:EC:0F:5B:FA:D6:43:62:5A:7E:EA:06:72:8C:3B:9B:84:68
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:19:E7:9C:9E:5C:7B:BA:FD:05:53:53:7C:A1:DC:B8:5C:7F:F5:4B:0D

    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         38:bc:3c:4e:f9:3f:4e:49:35:69:7b:c4:48:8f:5d:f7:ac:48:
         e1:10:90:45:2f:41:9d:4b:d5:54:6f:07:5d:d6:f6:33:1d:a8:
         6a:09:70:a7:fc:74:a6:58:43:2d:a3:5e:19:8a:9f:7c:18:2e:
         8d:82:38:99:f0:76:af:3d:00:a3:77:ff:e4:80:64:60:eb:fc:
         c8:1c:b1:12:bb:47:80:ab:50:56:cf:a8:c1:46:0c:aa:df:eb:
         94:1e:e3:47:8e:03:85:2c:52:f0:b9:81:9e:33:65:7a:46:79:
         64:77:4d:b4:62:ad:63:1a:ae:ee:1e:a2:4c:a6:5a:5b:f9:b8:
         e1:2c:e1:28:8a:83:17:08:99:90:15:9d:9a:e8:ca:1b:39:66:
         bb:8c:c3:33:fc:ff:9c:68:8b:ee:ea:31:a4:ff:e0:86:00:80:
         74:e3:2f:f2:7e:0c:b3:3c:74:37:1b:81:cf:de:53:02:8a:53:
         d2:fd:a3:56:7f:4a:ba:7d:e9:62:d0:77:0a:86:6b:58:da:d3:
         2f:34:57:eb:9e:29:a3:32:a6:f9:46:53:79:c9:77:c0:0e:04:
         21:13:39:b4:d3:b8:06:5d:55:f8:3d:17:9f:52:4f:37:e7:e3:
         82:f0:2a:12:3c:6c:cb:64:35:eb:f0:ea:a6:2f:db:0a:2d:0f:
         37:9d:ac:4c
```

I set up the certificates the following:

```
# CA:
openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 2048
openssl req -new -key ca.key -out ca-cert-request.csr -sha256
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -days 3650 -sha256 -keyout ca.key -out ca.crt -reqexts SAN -extensions SAN -subj '/CN=CAAUTH' -config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf; printf "[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:abc.xyz.com")
# mosquitto server:
openssl genrsa -out mosquitto.key 2048
openssl req -new -key mosquitto.key -out mosquitto-cert-request.csr -sha256
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -new -out mosquitto.crt -key mosquitto.key -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -newkey rsa:2048 -reqexts SAN -extensions SAN -subj '/CN=abc.xyz.com' -config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf; printf "[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:abc.xyz.com")
```

My mosquitto configuration file looks like this:

```
port 43340
allow_anonymous false
cafile /home/user/etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt
keyfile /home/user/etc/mosquitto/certs/mosquitto.key
certfile /home/user/etc/mosquitto/certs/mosquitto.crt
require_certificate true
log_type all
password_file /home/user/etc/mosquitto/passwd
```

After setting it up like this and restarting mosquitto my ESP32 connects (mqtt_client state: 0) and also mosquitto is running.
In the supervisord.log is see:

```
2022-09-14 15:48:09,408 DEBG 'mosquitto' stderr output:
1663163289: Received PUBLISH from ESP32 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'testtopic', ... (2 bytes))
```

So, I assume everything is working fine from the client side - but why isn't mosquitto running properly?
So far I tried:

- Multiple tutorials (including the quite recent one from [steves-internet-guide](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-tls/))
- Generating new Certificates

  - with different CN entires (IP, FQDN, localhost)
  - used a subjectAltName for the Certificate (but more like trial and error)
- modified the mosquitto.conf, e.g. require_certificate true/false
- **added the SAN** (only CA/server, both, with IP, DNS, different settings from other answers)

Comment: *" host name verification failed"* - The name you use to access must match the name in the certificate. In case of an IP address this means SAN with type IP and the specific IP address.

Comment: The ESP32 is most likely not doing any hostname verification

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Unfortunately I still cant make it work. :(
Do I have to enter in all certificates a SAN with IP – or just for the CA? As far as I understood it is required for each client/server communicating via TLS?  

That's how I set up my server cert signing:  
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server-cert-request.csr -sha256
openssl x509 -req -in server-cert-request.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -days 3650 -keyout server.key -out server.crt -subj "/CN=mosquittobroker" -addext "subjectAltName=DNS:abc.com,IP:x.x.x.x"

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73719387/edit) the question to show the output of the following command `openssl x509 -in server.crt -text -noout` so we can see if you have actually set the SAN entries properly as the commands you have listed are not what was suggested in the duplicate question.

Comment: So the cert you've posted the `-text` output for only has a DNS SAN entry, no IP SAN so it will fail to verify if you use the IP address to connect to the server.

Comment: I tried it with a IP SAN entry as well (also both IP and DNS) and of course changed the `mosquitto_sub` to use my domain name.
Is it correct that both CA and the server(mosquitto) certificate need a SAN entry?

Comment: Only the server cert needs SAN entries